# How to synchronize rest method in Webflux?

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

The problem is that when the `updateUser` is called at the same time, an incorrect balance update occurs.

```
2023-09-03T18:20:53.035+03:00  INFO 12668 --- [actor-tcp-nio-1] com.example.testsync.UserController      : current balance - 770.0, will be - 780.0
2023-09-03T18:20:53.043+03:00  INFO 12668 --- [actor-tcp-nio-1] com.example.testsync.UserController      : current balance - 770.0, will be - 780.0
2023-09-03T18:20:53.048+03:00  INFO 12668 --- [actor-tcp-nio-1] com.example.testsync.UserController      : current balance - 770.0, will be - 780.0
```

Controller looks like this:

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserController {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @PutMapping("/{userId}:updateBalance")
    public Mono<User> updateUser(@PathVariable("userId") Long userId, @RequestParam("diff") Double diff) {
        return userRepository.findById(userId)
                .flatMap(user -> {
                    log.info(String.format("current balance - %s, will be - %s", user.getBalance(), user.getBalance() + diff));
                    user.setBalance(user.getBalance() + diff);
                    return Mono.just(user);
                })
                .flatMap(userRepository::save);
    }
}
```

In theory, I need to organize the pipeline as follows:

```
req_1 -> 1. userRepository.findByid(userId) 2. userRepository.save(user)
req_2 -> 1. userRepository.findById(userId) 2. userRepository.save(user)
```

where req_1 and req_2 were called at the same time. But i don't know how to id :(

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule them to the same thread, so you don't need a synchronization (which is a blocking operation).

```
Scheduler dbScheduler = Schedulers.newSingle("db");

public Mono<User> updateUser(...) {
    return userRepository.findById(userId)
            .map(user -> {
                log.info(String.format("current balance - %s, will be - %s", user.getBalance(), user.getBalance() + diff));
                user.setBalance(user.getBalance() + diff);
                return user;
            })
            .flatMap(userRepository::save)
            //
            // tell Reactor to schedule it to a single thread execution:
            .subscribeOn(dbScheduler);
}
```

Comment: same issue. I've pushed my code on github - https://github.com/dpiat/reactive-sync/tree/master, so you can check it